# Modeling objects like this

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, vertices

Hi I am quite new to blender and only start using it for a little more over a week. I followed some tutorials on textures, nodes, basic animations and modeling but I feel like I am sort of getting stuck now.

So anyway I am trying to model this object in the the first picture I uploaded. Do you have any tips of how to approach this? I have been trying myself for a while now but I feel like I made the object way to complicated for myself by beveling the corners and using the spin tool to extrude. It's hard to get the shape the right way while at the same time it looks like a simple object. (See the next pictures)

Or can you recommend me some tutorial which will make me better at modeling objects like this? I really want to dig deeper into modeling first so I am able to model the right shapes first. But I just can't find the right tutorials which help me improve in this way. [image]

[[image: CoverIn works]

[image: Render]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can begin with a circle that you extrude inwards, delete a part:

[image]

Extrude some edges to give it the G shape:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Mirror:

[image]

Give it thickness with the *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

Continue to work on the shape, apply the *Solidify*, give it a *Subdivision Surface*, bevel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I mannaged to make a start like this. https://ibb.co/wMdFVdJ

Comment: What is the best way to add the buttons on the side of the object make it a seperate shape or extrude this from the same object?

Comment: make them separate meshes (or separate objects), it's more logical to make separate meshes (or objects) when they are separate objects in real life

Comment: Ok so I made the buttons a as seperate meshes and placed them on the base model. But I having trouble rounding the corners now. I used the solidfyer and was able to figure out how to round the edges with it. But I still feel it

Comment: But I still feel it's a still flat any idea how I could make it look more smooth? And I noticed when adding textures on seperate faces I had problems with the inside as it seem to affect both out side and inside. Should I just create a duplicate again for the inside to place on the faces or is it possible to do it on the same mesh or face. Meaning on the other side of the face?

Comment: If you want to round some angles, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier (don't apply it) and use the bevel tool to control the roundness of some edges. But what you ask is llike basic modeling questions, it would be hard to explain step by step in Blender Stack Exchange, which is rather made for precise questions, maybe you should follow some tutorials on how to model etc

Comment: https://ibb.co/WckZ73V
https://ibb.co/Sn82k5m
https://ibb.co/6YQ82Hy

Comment: Allright thanks! Can you recommend me some good tutorials that could help me to model better objects like this by any chance?

Comment: Take a look at my edit to see how you could bevel the angles. As for the tutos, I generally recommend Grant Abbitt because he's the first to come to my mind but there are a lot of good tutorials